# How Animated an Image when scales using React Native?

Tags: react-native, animation

I have currently a version working with Transform scale but I want to animated this.. here is the code.. I  have a array with images and each image is scaling right now but I want to animated this and when image is pressed will scale and if there was another image already scaled I will scaled down the previous image.

```
  const [vibePressed, setVibePressed] = useState(null);
  const [prevVibePressed, setPrevVibePressed] = useState(null);

function onVibePress(index) {
  if (index === vibePressed) {
    console.log("large the vibe");
} else {
   console.log("set the vibe pressed to state");
   setVibePressed(index);
   setPrevVibePressed(vibePressed);
 }
}

 {vibe.vibeImageUrl && (
 <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => onVibePress(index)}>
            <Animated.Image
              source={{ uri: vibe.vibeImageUrl }}
              style={{
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
                borderRadius: 30,
                borderWidth: 1,
                borderColor: "white",
                transform: [{ scale: index === vibePressed ? 1.5 : 1 }],
              }}
            />
          </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
)
```